# How to get the added values from the start of a numerical list up till a certain point determined by an input?

Tags: python, list

I have a list that I want to be able to reference in a way where I can get the added values from the start of the list to a certain position, determined by an input.

here is something i tried but it doesn't work:

```
leap_year = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
value = 0
months = int(input())
for x in leap_year:
    while x < leap_year[months - 1]:
        value = value + x
print(value)
```

A possible output could look like this:

```
months = 5 #by an input
value = 152 #by adding the first 5 terms in the sequence
```

Comment: Hi, can you add a sample input and output for what you want to acheive?

Comment: `leap_year = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
sub_list = leap_year[:3]`

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Can you also provide an output?

Comment: sum(leap_year[:int(input())])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?
If you pass input as `4` , it will extract upto 4th element:

```
leap_year = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
value = 0
months = int(input())
output = leap_year[:months]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[31, 29, 31, 30]
```

Comment: yes this helps thanks! I can then run a for loop to add them all up

Comment: `sum(output)` will do the job @Stevethellama

Comment: sum(leap_year[:months]) <<this is better

Answer (score 0):

Replace your while loop with this line `value = sum(leap_year[:month])`. Your full code might look like below.

```
leap_year = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

months = int(input())
value = sum(leap_year[:month])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
leap_year = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31] # index starting with 1 as month
value = 0
months = int(input('Enter Month: '))
for x in range(1, months+1):
    value = value + leap_year[x]
print(value)
```